# two sequences whose difference converges to zero

Tags: notation

Is there a name for the relationship between sequences $A_n$ and $B_n$ which means that the sequence $A_n - B_n$ converges to zero?  I want to say something like "sequence $A$ converges to sequence $B$" which might not mean the right thing, or something like "sequences $A$ and $B$ converge" which certainly doesn't mean what I want it to.  Sorry if this question is too noob.

Comment: I'm tempted to write $A_n \sim B_n$ for this, but I would actually use that notation for $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n/B_n = 1$.

Comment: Perhaps that the two sequences are asymptotic? 

Comment: How about $A_n-B_n\to0$? And what is "noob"?

Comment: $A_n$ and $B_n$ are "asymptotically equal" - http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Asymptotically_Equal

Comment: Saying sequence A converges to sequence B seems like saying that $1/n$ converges to $1/n^2$ as $n\to\infty$, a statement which makes me feel queasy and shouty at the same time

Comment: noob: newbie (several other meanings with various shades abound, but i guess this particular one was meant).

Comment: @Yemon Choi Did you notice the title now is in fact a answer to the question itself :) 

Comment: @Vagabond which is why I'm afraid I don't think much of the question, such as it is :(

Comment: What's wrong with "The sequences differ by a null sequence"?

Comment: @Suvrit: FWIW, "noob" is thought to be derogatory, as opposed to "newb"/"newbie".

Answer (score 4):

Note that this is an equivalence relation. In fact, if you start with just the rational numbers, then this relation for Cauchy sequences of rationals is usually called "equivalence", and the equivalence classes can then be identified with precisely the field of real numbers. (This is my personal favorite way for constructing the reals from the rationals.) So I think that in any reasonable context it would be quite reasonable to just call such sequences equivalent.

Comment: So making "equivalent" an even more overloaded term than it already
is :-)

Comment: Well, yes, but notice I said "in any reasonable context". This is not at all likely to be a universal definition, but only one used in some limited context---such as the one I mentioned, the construction o the reals from the rationals.

Answer (score 3):

In one context they are called equivalent. If $A_n$ and $B_n$ are
Cauchy sequences in a metric space $X$, they are called equivalent when
$d(A_n,B_n)$ converges to 0, and the completion of $X$ consists of 
equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences. This can match your 
$A_n-B_n$ in cases where $X$ is a subset of a normed linear space.

Answer (score 1):

For sequences of real numbers there is a French term: "suites adjacentes" (may be translated as adjacent sequences) which means that the two sequences satisfy $\lim_{k\to\infty}(A_k-B_k)=0$, but with $A_k$ decreasing and $B_k$ increasing.

Comment: Indeed, but the non-increasing/non-decreasing condition makes it a lot more restrictive than the OP's question.

Comment: Yes. I thought it may suggest a suitable terminology.

Answer (score 1):

To define convergence one needs a "metric" or a concept of "distance", and there can be many different notion of "distances". For example one can consider $\lim_{n -> \infty} \frac {1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n |(A_k - B_k)|^p$. Or alternatively  $\lim_{n -> \infty} \frac {1}{n} \sum_{k=n}^{2n} |(A_k - B_k)|^p$.

Though your notion of distance is much stronger than the above, to be precise its $\limsup_{n->\infty}|A_n-B_n|$. So if the "distance" between two sequences is zero one can define an equivalence relation in a natural way and then you do actually get a proper metric. As everyone has mentioned this is how we go about constructing the real number system using Cauchy sequences.

So, I would suggest the sequence  <strike>{A eventually converge to B or}</strike>, as per Willie Wong's suggestion A is asymptotically equivalent to B.

Comment: First statement is untrue.

Comment: how can we talk about convergence without a notion of distance ?

Comment: You only need a topology, not a metric. You probably want a Hausdorff topology, because otherwise the limit will not necessarily be unique.

Comment: point taken, I made that statement to emphasize that it matters a lot what notion of distance (if you like topolgy) we are considering when we are talking about convergence... so just saying two sequence converges without clarifying what the notion of convergence is inadequate. The title now edited by Yemon Choi is in fact the perfect answer to the original question which incidentally was "two sequences converge to each other" 

Comment: In my book, saying two sequences converge to each other is like saying you can cancel the d's in dy/dx, only even more like someone scraping nails down a blackboard

Comment: Thanks @Yemon it was my inability to nail down the exact source of the screeching sound :-) and I ended up adding more noise am afraid, but then that's the way I learn I suppose, and for me that's the point